# Javafx TreeView listener

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I have a TreeView in my application and I want to add a listener to get the item that is selected. I currently have:

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {

            }           
        });
```

Error received: `The method addListener(ChangeListener<? super TreeItem<String>>) in the type 
 ObservableValue<TreeItem<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (new 
 ChangeListener<String>(){})`

What is the correct way to add a listener to a TreeView in javafx?

It is being declared as `TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(object);`

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to fix this issue was by turning it into a lambda expression like this:

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> { 
// Body would go here

});
```

I don't know why my first method did not work but this does work.

Comment: The first method did not work because the `ChangeListener`'s generic type was `String` when in fact it should have been `TreeItem<String>`. It worked with the lambda expression because the (correct) argument type is inferred.